# frida-server : Unable to connect

Tags: android, adb, frida

**Failed to enumerate processes: unable to connect to remote frida-server: closed**

frida-server is running as you can see in the output of  `su top`  command.

both frida and adb is able to find the usb android device.

- I am using android 10 rooted.
- Frida version is 12.9.4 for both windows(pip) and android(frida-server).

[image]

[image]

Comment: How old is the "Minimal ADB and fastboot" installation? Some years ago the ADB interface on PC side was changed, hence if the ADB version is too old frida may not be compatible with your ADB. In any way it is better to use recent version of adb from Android SDK.

Comment: It's 1.4.3.  Ok....let me try this

Comment: My adb outputs `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41 Version 30.0.1-6435776`

Comment: same issue ): ):  ...I switched to android sdk(Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41                                                                                     Version 30.0.1-6435776). Have you tried frida-server on android 10?

Comment: For testing start frida-server in foreground (without `&`). Then you will see if it really starts and keeps running or if it crashes.

Comment: I tried Magisk frida module form Magisk Manager [git-repo](https://github.com/ViRb3/magisk-frida) and it worked :) ...anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This code fixed my problem, run this in terminal

```
$ adb shell
# su
# /data/local/tmp/frida-server &
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason Frida Magisk Module works perfectly fine on Android 10...I got lucky.[image]

[image: s]

Answer (score 1):

@Jimale is correct. I spent 3 or more hours to find it out.

Obviously , the `frida-server` is not start at all.

You MUST type `su root` before you run `frida-server` in your rooted android phone.

If you already install 3rd-party magisk-module, such like "adb root", you still HAVE TO switch to root user manually by typing `su root`.

To make sure that the current user in adb shell is root, please type : `ifconfig` to see if you are the actual root.

If you are the root user, you will have the rights to see the `ifconfig` result. otherwise you will see `you don't have permission...`